# OLEDB to MDB on shared location

Tags: oledb, mdb2

Ok, this time I've created an app to write and update an MDB DB using OLEDB.
the MDB reside in a shared folder on the network which my account has access to.

every function works ok on my local machine when I test (add, edit and delete).
But when I moved the project to the IIS server, the application could not update the DB.

Now I know it is a permission issue, but what user account shall I grant access to the shared folder? is it IUSR (which is not available on the network) or else?

I even changed the app pool to use my account but it failed.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide: application type, language, what error do you get?

Comment: ASP.net C#, I don't get the error and I Know it cant connect to the DB, as I said: it is working locally.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I used the web server name and grant it the access, and it worked.
Thank you guys anyway.